# How to get the Foursquare OAuth request code, using C# inside Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, foursquare, sharpsquare

I'm using [SharpSquare](https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare) for C# modeling of the Foursquare API, and I'm getting stuck at step 1.

1. Get a "code" from Foursquare
2. Get an access token based on return url and the "code"
3. Query API

**The SharpSquare documentation shows this:**

```
if (Request["code"] != null) {
    sharpSquare.GetAccessToken(redirectUri, Request["code"]);
    ...
}
else {
    HyperLink.NavigateUrl = sharpSquare.GetAuthenticateUrl(redirectUri);
}
```

I'm trying to query the Foursquare API from **within an ASP.NET Web API method**. I can't do this:  `HyperLink.NavigateUrl = sharpSquare.GetAuthenticateUrl(redirectUri);`

What can I do to get the "code"? (*I've tried various WebClient() & WebRequest/WebResponse attempts, just can't quite get it to work*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically this authentication is a 2-step process. First you need to generate authentication URL using `GetAuthenticateUrl()` call - and redirect user to that URL. After user successfully authenticates, FourSquare will call the redirect URL you provided - passing the `code` parameter - which you will need to exchange for access token with `GetAccessToken()` call.

here is a sample MVC code:

```
public ActionResult UserClicksAuthenticate()
{
    var redirectUri = Request.Url.Authority + this.Url.Action("AuthorizeCallback", new {userCode = "userCode"});
    var sharpSquare = new SharpSquare(clientId, clientSecret);
    var authUrl = sharpSquare.GetAuthenticateUrl(redirectUri);

    return new RedirectResult(authUrl, permanent: false);
}

public ActionResult AuthorizeCallback(string code, string userCode)
{
    var redirectUri = Request.Url.Authority + this.Url.Action("AuthorizeCallback", new { userCode = userCode });

    var sharpSquare = new SharpSquare(clientId, clientSecret);    
    var accessToken = sharpSquare.GetAccessToken(redirectUri, code);

    // need this in order to make calls to API
    // it's redundant because token is already set in GetAccessToken() call but it helps to understand the workflow better. 
    sharpSquare.SetAccessToken(accessToken);

    List<VenueHistory> venues = sharpSquare.GetUserVenueHistory();

    return View("Index");
}

public ActionResult GetVenues()
{
    var sharpSquare = new SharpSquare(clientId, clientSecret, appToken);    

    List<VenueHistory> venues = sharpSquare.GetUserVenueHistory();

    return View("Index");
}
```

`userCode` above is just a arbitrary string you can pass in your redirect url so can recover the user context in the callback function. For example, this can be page code, or user id, or event name - whatever your logic requires.

**UPDATE**: as it turns out, topic starter was interested in "user-less" access (see [FourSquare dev page here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless)). Indeed, for these actions you do not need to get access token, you only need APP ID & SECRET. Looking at [SharpSquare implementation](https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare/blob/master/Core/SharpSquare.cs), I noticed that there is a there is an [overload](https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare/blob/master/Core/SharpSquare.cs#L90) with `bool unauthenticated` parameter:

```
private FourSquareSingleResponse<T> GetSingle<T>(string endpoint, bool unauthenticated) where T : FourSquareEntity
```

which indeed only requires app id/secret [when calling API](https://github.com/TICLAB/SharpSquare/blob/master/Core/SharpSquare.cs#L149).

This parameter is set to `true` when the following public methods are called:

```
public Venue GetVenue(string venueId)
public List<Venue> SearchVenues(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
public List<Checkin> GetVenueHereNow(string venueId, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
public List<Tip> GetVenueTips(string venueId, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
public List<Photo> GetVenuePhotos(string venueId, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
public List<Link> GetVenueLinks(string venueId)
public Tip GetTip(string tipId)
public Special GetSpecial(string specialId)
```

that means you do not need access token if you want to call any of these methods in your WebAPI action:

```
public ActionResult SearchVenues()
{
    var sharpSquare = new SharpSquare(clientId, clientSecret);    

    List<VenueHistory> venues = sharpSquare.SearchVenues(<<params>>);

    return View(venues);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to do that all inside one Web API action, instead of two MVC actions. It's not to authenticate a user, it's to make a call to the Foursquare API to pull venue data (using my app's credentials). That's why I was wondering how to do this using a C# `WebClient()`. Any ideas?

Comment: in order to call API (to get venue data) you need to have access token. If you already have it, then you should use SharpSquare(APP_ID, APP_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN) constructor and then call the API function. See my edit - i added GetVenues() function in there. HOWEVER - if you do NOT have the access token, then you cannot get it without user interaction - i.e. without user signing in on FourSquare login page - even if you know the password. That's how FB, Twitter, and all other OAuth2 sites work. That means you can't get venues in a **single** call in your WebApi controller.

Comment: once again - app credentials (i assume you mean app id/secret) mean nothing - meaning you cannot call API just by having them. App is only valid in the context of USER - that's why you need access token. So in order to get it, a user should approve your app to do certain actions on user's behalf. That means FourSquare login page is unavoidable. You MUST redirect user to it so he can authenticate your app. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome information, helps a lot. Using SquareSharp is there no way to do userless access to the Foursquare API? https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless

Comment: you are correct - there is a bunch of userless functions supported by SharpSquare. I updated my answer. But your question wasn't quite clear - you talked about authentications etc :) Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you... that is exactly what I needed. Sorry I worded it so strangely, I just noticed the Foursquare API's "user-less" endpoints today. You've been a huge help.